# How can I dynamically bind / inject a database connection string into my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control

I am using MVC and my application is an administrative application that can connect to multiple datasources.

I would like some suggestions on how I can pass a connection string to my controller. Any suggestions that I could then do research on would be much appreciated.

So far I have seen examples like this:

```
   protected IProductsRepository ProductsRepository = null; 

   public ProductsController(IProductsRepository productsRepository) 
   { 
      ProductsRepository = productsRepository; 
   }
```

But how does the controller get injected with the correct value for the productsRepository? I saw some mention of IOC products but I am not sure where to start and are these products not more suited to very large applications?

Comment: Autofac is dead easy, read here: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your full requirements, here are a couple things for you to look into:

A dependency injection framework like StructureMap. Here is an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-structuremap.aspx).

To simply handle controller construction yourself, you will need to create a custom controller factory implementing `IControllerFactory`. This article on the [MVC Application Execution Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612.aspx) should help you get a better understanding.

After you implement an `IControllerFactory`, you can wire it up in the Global.asax like so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CustomControllerFactory));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. I'm thinking ahead and wondering about MVC4. Also would like to stay with MSOFT products. Is there some way I can do DI and just use my own code or do I really need to use some outside product?

Comment: @SamanthaJ The second point I made about creating a custom controller factory is where controller instantiation occurs in the Asp.Net MVC pipeline. You could use that for instantiating your controllers with whatever values you want manually and wouldn't have to use a DI framework.

Comment: Thanks I will look into your last comment as a possible solution. But it makes me wonder what then do these other products offer if I could code up the things manually?

Comment: @SamanthaJ as your dependencies become more nested, DI frameworks help lessen the pain of manually wiring up your classes even if you are using factories. However, in an application that does not have much complication in the instantiation of your controllers then using a simple factory class can help you manage your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) as an IOC container. It is not part of the .NET framework, but it is from Microsoft. Another option would be [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/). This is part of the framework, but is not only an IOC framework.

EDIT:
As @Daniel suggested there is a Nuget package for MVC3 at http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc3. I use Unity a lot in my projects.

Comment: I was looking at Unity but is that an easy fit for MVC ?

Comment: Yes it is. Install this library using Nuget: http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc3 The setup of the container is really easy, just follow the Readme. With that library you make sure, that your dependencies are correctly disposed at the end of a request.

Comment: @Daniel - Can you comment on what Craig said about my just creating a simple factory class. A bit of background. The application has about 20 controllers, 20 service layer classes and 20 entitites. It's a windows Azure cloud application that uses MVC.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea. Every time a controller get's a new dependency, you have to change your factory. If you use constructor injection, Unity will resolve the new dependency for you. Moreover you get lifetime management for free, if you use a Ioc container.